# Do there exist integers $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{n-1},a_n$ such that $a_i+a_{i+1}+a_{i+3}=1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory

I am curious about the existence of a sequence of integers $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{n-1},a_n$ for some $n\ge1$ with the property that for all positive integers $i$,
$$a_i+a_{i+1}+a_{i+3}=1$$
where we compute indices modulo $n$ as necessary.

My interest lies in the more general case of any finite weighted sum of indices relative to $i$; the case above is simply the first which seems nontrivial. (The motivation for this comes in thinking about "tiling" $\mathbb{Z}$ with finite weighted tiles, where we want to lay down an integer number of copies in each position: the existence of such a series of $a_i$ amounts to the existence of a periodic tiling.)

It is easy to see that $n$ must be a multiple of three, by adding all congruences together; I can also rule out individual cases of $n=3$ or $n=6$, but I don't see how to get all $n$ in general. It would suffice to show that the vectors $(1,1,0,1,0,\ldots,0)$ and its cyclic rotations are linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$, but I'm not sure how to do this either.

As a remark, this is *not* true if we replace $(i,i+1,i+3)$ with $(i,i+1,i+5)$, so the argument must hinge on the specific offsets somehow.

Comment: Are you familiar with the generating function interpretation of this question? If yes, you are asking for the factors of $ 1+ x + x^2 + \ldots + x^{n-1} $ in  $ \mathbb{Z}[x] / [ x^n - 1 ] $. The particular case asks if $1 + x + x^3$ is ever a factor.

Comment: There's no solution for $n\le 10000$, so i'm guessing the answer is no.

Comment: I have a proof that the answer is no, I'll post it in a few hours, right now I don't have the time. Nice question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the recurrence relation $a_{k+3}=1-a_{k+1}-a_k$. From the theory of linear recurrence relations we have $a_k = \frac{1}{3}+c_1\alpha^k+c_2\beta^k+c_3\gamma^k$ where $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are the roots of $x^3+x+1=0$, for some constants $c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$.

We want the sequence to also satisfy for some $n$ the equations $a_{n-2}+a_{n-1} +a_1=1$, $a_{n-1}+a_n +a_2=1$ and $a_n+a_1 +a_3=1$. This translate into the system

$$
\begin{array}{l}
c_1(\alpha^{n-2}+\alpha^{n-1}+\alpha)+c_2(\beta^{n-2}+\beta^{n-1}+\beta)+c_3(\gamma^{n-2}+\gamma^{n-1}+\gamma)=0\\
c_1(\alpha^{n-1}+\alpha^n+\alpha^2)+c_2(\beta^{n-1}+\beta^n+\beta^2)+c_3(\gamma^{n-1}+\gamma^n+\gamma^2)=0\\
c_1(\alpha^n+\alpha+\alpha^3)+c_2(\beta^n+\beta+\beta^3)+c_3(\gamma^n+\gamma+\gamma^3)=0\\
\end{array}
$$

After some calculations, the determinant of the system is
$$
\frac{(\alpha-\beta)(\beta-\gamma)(\gamma-\alpha)(\alpha^n-1)(\beta^n-1)(\gamma^n-1)}{\alpha^2\beta^2\gamma^2}
$$

None of the factors can be $0$, so the determinant of the system is not $0$ and the only solution for the system is $c_1=c_2=c_3=0$ which means that the only sequence satisfying the requested conditions is constant sequence $a_k = \frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Thanks! Given the involvement of this procedure, it sounds like it doesn't yield a particularly fast algorithm for deciding this question in general? (I guess zero determinant is necessary but not sufficient for a solution anyway, so it wouldn't resolve all cases.)

Comment: Once you have the closed form solutiion for $a_k$, there is another proof using the numerical values of three roots $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, which round to $\alpha = -0.6823$, $\beta = .3411 + 1.1615i$, $\gamma = .3411 - 1.1615i$. If $c_2$ or $c_3$ is nonzero it follows that $|a_k| \to \infty$. If $c_2=c_3=0$ it follows that $|a_k| \to \frac{1}{3}$. In particular $\alpha_k$ cannot be an eventually bounded integer sequence. For a general linear recurrence relation, if no root of its corresponding characteristic polynomial has complex norm equal to $1$, the same proof should hold.